# What reputation is deducted on answer migration?

Tags: support, migration, reputation

I think when an answer migrated, reputation deduction depends on the number of upvotes on that answer. [One of my answers](https://superuser.com/a/977928/416314) was migrated from Web Applications to Super User site. Before migration my reputation was `1446` on Web Applications. But once it got migrated, my reputation changed to `1430`. Total deduction is 16 reputation. But on Super User my reputation increment is only `10` which is correct because answer has only one upvote.

My question is can anyone explain about that other `6` reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 posts that you submitted suggested edits for were removed. This causes you to lose 6 reputation. 2 reputation for each edit.

When viewing your reputation, if you check the box at the bottom of the page called "show removed posts" it should display these posts and the subsequent reputation loss.

Comment: Thanks Barry. I got message about answer migration and same time all detection reputation, so I thought it is related to migration only. Just now I saw removed post and got to know. :)